# Where do i add the timer code in my program ?

Tags: java, android-studio

This is my top of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";
    private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
        "http://10.0.0.1:8098/?cmd=nothing",
        "http://192.168.1.10:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
    private String iptouse = "";
    private TextView text;
    private boolean connectedtoipsuccess = false;
    private int counter = 0;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    TextView timerTextView;
    long startTime = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        currentActivity = this;
        initTTS();
    }
```

And i want to add this code to my program so when i'm running my program i will the timer running.

```
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setText("start");
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button b = (Button) v;
                if (b.getText().equals("stop")) {
                    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                    b.setText("start");
                } else {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
                    b.setText("stop");
                }
            }
        });
    }

  @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setText("start");
    }
```

What i want it to do is once i'm running the program the timer will start.

But i can't find how and where to add this part of the timer code.
I tried in the onCreate and i tried after the onCreate but it give errors since you can just add @override

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to set up another class (either in the same class or in its own class) and implement Runnable then from your on create make instance to that runnable.